# change css display property when it has a specific class - Javascript

Tags: javascript, css

When my button has the class of rotate , i would like to then change the form's display from none to flex

```
    const button = document.querySelector('.expand');
    const form = document.querySelector('input-form');

    button.addEventListener('click', rotate);

    function rotate(e) {
     this.classList.toggle('rotate')
     if(this.classList.contains(rotate)) {
       form.style.display = 'flex';
     } else {
       form.style.display = 'none';
     }
    }
```

I have made a codepen to try figure this out , thank you :) 
https://codepen.io/o-sewell/pen/NpzxxR

Comment: did you have pressed `F12`? The console would spit with errors.

Comment: This is what CSS does for a living.

Comment: You have typo errors - 'input-form' is missing the period for class selection `('.input-form')` (otherwise it is null) and `classList.contains` needs a string `('rotate')`

Answer (score 1):

Why not just use CSS to achieve this:

```
.input-form {
    display: none; /*** default display ***/
}
.input-form.rotate {
    display: flex; /*** will be display: flex when the rotate class is toggled on ***/
}
```

The form will not be `display: flex` till the class `rotate` is appended. You can then completely remove the inline styling that the JS applies (`form.style.display = 'flex'; form.style.display = 'none';`)

Here's a fiddle for you with my updated CSS and cleaner JS: https://jsfiddle.net/m8eu5yv9/

Here's the updated code:

```js
const button = document.querySelector('.expand');
const form = document.querySelector('.input-form');

button.addEventListener('click', rotate);

function rotate(e) {
  form.classList.toggle('rotate')
}
```

```css
.input-form {
    display: none; /*** default display ***/
}
.input-form.rotate {
    display: flex; /*** will be display: flex when the rotate class is toggled on ***/
}
```

```html
<button class="expand">
  Toggle
</button>

<div class="input-form">
  <p>Inner content</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi David , i tried adding this to my css but isn't working

Comment: @OliverSewell I've modified your JS slightly, try this: https://jsfiddle.net/m8eu5yv9/

Comment: the whole form is rotating now when the button is clicked and button isn't rotating

Comment: @OliverSewell then you might have some other code doing some other things? My solution works with the limited information you provided :-) My answer is meant to guide you as I don;t know your project like you do...

Comment: Thank you i see what you were trying to do and how it was much simpler. My initial code did have some errors but now fixed it is working how i wanted although may be quite complicate but thank you david i appreciate your help

Comment: @OliverSewell no problem, glad i could help. Remember to mark an answer as correct if it helps you out - it might help someone else in the future who stumbles upon this question :-)

Answer (score 0):

You could just toggle a class for the form.

```js
const button = document.querySelector('.expand');
const form = document.querySelector('.input-form');

button.addEventListener('click', rotate);

function rotate(e) {
 this.classList.toggle('rotate')
 form.classList.toggle('flex');
}
```

```css
.flex { display: flex }
```